# Ruby on rails form validation doesn't working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I try to validate a signup form and display an error if it's needed, but whatever I write in this form (or not write), there are all errors possible displayed (invalid email, blank field etc...). I followed a tutorial and I can't see where is the problem.

Here is my form :

```
<div class="row">
<%= form_for(:user, :url => {:controller => 'users', :action => 'create'}) do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, :class => "col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4 field", :placeholder => "Name", :maxlength => "80" %></br>
  <%= f.text_field :email, :class => "col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4 field", :placeholder => "Email", :maxlength => "80" %></br>
  <%= f.password_field :password, :class => "col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4 field", :placeholder => "Password", :maxlength => "80" %></br>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :class => "col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4 field", :placeholder => "Password confirmation", :maxlength => "80" %></br>
  <%= f.submit :Submit, :value => "Sign up", :class => "col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-5", :id => "signup" %>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-link col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4"><%=link_to "Already registered ?", home_path%></button>
<% end %>
```

my controller :

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def signup
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[user_params])
    if @user.save
    end
    render "signup"
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,      :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

and my model :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :password

  before_save :encrypt_password
  after_save :clear_password

  EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\z/i
  validates :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :length => { :in     => 3..20 }
  validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :format =>     EMAIL_REGEX
  validates :password, :confirmation => true #password_confirmation attr
  validates_length_of :password, :in => 6..20, :on => :create

  def encrypt_password
    if password.present?
      self.salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
      self.encrypted_password= BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, salt)
    end
  end
end
```

Here is my shared_secret :

```
<% if @user.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      The form contains <%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %>.
    </div>
    <ul>
    <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: how does your `shared/error_messages` look? Are you saying that the error message is always displayed or its not displayed irrespective of what you do?

Comment: I edited my question. In fact, the shared secret is displaying `The form contains 5 errors.` all the time, and I get my 5 errors, like `Name can't be blank` for example.   Whatever I send in the form, errors are here.

Comment: change in form `form_for(:user` to `form_for @user`, and in general this string can looks like `<%= form_for @user do |f| %>` because `rails` understands which controller to use and what action you need

Comment: Always the same problem, however I get this in the debug message : `user: !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
  name: Baptiste
  email: ''
  password: ''
  password_confirmation: ''` so I guess that object is set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using strong parameters, but incorrectly: Simply do `User.new(user_params)`

`user_params`, as defined, becomes a hash of permitted params and it's value. The original `params` hash, has no `user_params` keys.